# Dismiss all dialogs in one click

Tags: android, dialog

I want to hide all dialogs when clicking this button:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(FullscreenActivity.this)
                                .setTitle("Error!")
                                .setMessage(".......")
                                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
//hide all dialogs
                                        }
                                    }).setIcon(R.drawable.icon_error).show();
```

How can I do that? I want to close all previously opened dialogs with this.

Comment: Declare global and do what you want ...

Comment: i m with @AM Declare global and hide

Comment: make globle object of all dialogs and call dialog1.cancel();dialog2.cancel(); and so on if you want more help show your code of all dialogs

Comment: I want to close all previously opened dialogs with this. They are still open.

Answer (score 1):

```
May this help you.Create common method for calling dialog :

// Declare this as global variables 
    public static AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    public AlertDialog dialog;
    public  Vector<AlertDialog> dialogs = new Vector<AlertDialog>();

public void alertDialog(String message) {
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(message).setPositiveButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialogs.remove(dialog);
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        dialog=builder.create();
        dialogs.add(dialog);
        dialog.show();

    }
```

Comment: with dialog.show(); the dialog is shown twice and opened dialogs are not canceled, I still have to click all other buttons.

Comment: SO, you have to do is Create another through which you show dialog and in that write dialogs.add(dialog) and One more method for removing all dialogs dialogs.remove(dialog) and call accordingly